# Parse onclick="setLocation(...)" with jQuery / prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I have this tag in example:

`<button onclick="setLocation('http://mysite.com/checkout/cart/add/product/17/')" />`

What I need to do is initiate ajax request on button click. I need URL segment "product/17" from above appended to my ajax url. Any clever ways to extract this without using regex? HTML is not changable - **however** I can modify the URL, and in that case I would need to extract the exact URL from onclick attribute.

So I either need URL or "product/17" extracted from onclick attribute, hopefully without using regex.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if no RegExp usage, and no criteria for parsing the string, here is the simplest solution:

```
var str = ​$("button").attr("onclick"​​​​);
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("add/") + 4, str.length - 3);​
```

Comment: that's basically it, and it allows parsing of additional parameters as well. thanks

Comment: @Netismine You may use shim for compatibility. See the details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with the split() function:

```
var url = 'http://mysite.com/checkout/cart/add/product/17';
var array = url.split('add/');
alert(array[1]);​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: That does not answer the question though.

Comment: Because the OP wants to parse the whole `onclick` attribute value, not the URL only.